# Unicode character in Select Query using LIKE in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting wrong output if i use Unicode tamil characters in `LIKE` MySQL query

```
Select * from tbl_name where colName LIKE 'ச%';
```

In the above Query I am getting records starting with `சொ,சு,சே,சூ,சா,சி.` what I need is the letter starting `ச`  only.

colHWord
சகதி
சக்தி
சகாயம்
சகுனம்
சங்கம்
சங்கிரகம்
சங்கு
சடை
சத்தியம்
சந்தடி
சந்தர்ப்பம்
சந்திரகலை
சந்தேகம்
சபதம்
சப்பு
சபை
சம்பிரமம்
சம்புடம்
சமம்
சம்மதம்
சமயம்
சமன்
சரி
சரிவு
சலனன்
சறுக்கு
சனி
சாக்கு
சாட்சி
சாணம்
சாத்து
சாதனம்
சாதனை
சாதி
சாந்து
சாபம்
சாமர்த்தியம்
சாய்
சாய்வு
சாயை
சார்
சார்பு
சாவகாசம்
சாறு
சிக்கனம்
சிகரம்
சிங்காரம்
சித்திரம்
சித்திரி
சிதறு
சிதைவு
சிந்து
சிலை
சிவப்பு
சிறகு
சிறப்பு
சிறப்புவிதி
சிற்றுண்டி
சிறை
சின்னம்
சினேகம்
சினை
சீவு
சுடு
சுமை
சுரண்டு
சுரணை
சுருக்கம்
சுருக்கு
சுருங்கு
சுருட்டு
சுவர்
சுவை
சுழி
சுற்றம்
சுற்று
சூரியன்
சூழ்ச்சி
சூழ்வோர்
செதுக்கு
செம்மறி
செய்தி
செருக்கு
செருகு
செல்வம்
செலவு
செழிப்பு
செறிவு
சேர்
சேவகம்
சேவை
சேறு
சேனை
சொரி
சொல்
சோபானம்
சோம்பு
சோறு
சௌக்கியம்

Comment: what is the character set in mysql Table and column ?

Comment: Please show us the mysql create table stmt and the values.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_tamilvt` (
  `colID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `colHword` text,
  `colJword` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`colID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Could it be a collation problem? Can you give us the result of `show table status like 'tbl_name'`? (it's better to add it in your answer directly - easier to read)

Comment: @mcbalaji change mysql charater set : utf8,and  Collation : utf8_general_ci for your column and table to :D

Comment: already it is utf8,and Collation : utf8_general_ci for column and table

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE BINARY in place of %, something like this

```
Select * from tbl_name where colName LIKE BINARY 'ச';
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly `LIKE` should work with `'ச%'`.

But you can try to use the unicode as hex value OR
you could also use the `REGEXP` operator.

Adjust your SQL statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE colName  REGEXP '^ச.*';
```

Comment: The result is same when i use REGEXP

Answer (score 0):

சொ,சு,சே,சூ,சா,சி are the combination of two Unicode character so query must be specific to pull ச. Below is the one of the  way to omit other letters

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE colName LIKE 'ச%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சா%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சி%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சு%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சொ%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சே%' AND colName NOT LIKE 'சூ%';

There should some other way using REGEXP, But I'm unable to find it.